# How to open a new tab on the left in Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, autohotkey, google-chrome-extensions, browser-tabs

Every new link you open with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + mouseclick opens a new tab on the right.

However, there are certain situations where it is helpful to open a new tab to the left.

Is there any shortcut to achieve this? Something like <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + mouseclick would be handy.

If not, is there any workaround (like a plugin or an Autohotkey script)?

*I think it's not built-in so I tag the question with "autohotkey" as well.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Windows there is no shortcut to move tabs left or right, so you can use an extension like [rearrange-tabs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rearrange-tabs/ccnnhhnmpoffieppjjkhdakcoejcpbga)
to set the shortcut for moving current tab to the right (Alt-Shift-Right) and then use Autohotkey script to combine into one action:

```
#If winActive("ahk_exe chrome.exe") 
^+lbutton::
    send ^{lbutton}
    send !+{right}
return
```

It basically binds Ctrl-Shift-click to do Ctrl-click then Alt-Shift-Right to move the tab one position to the right.

Comment: Wow, amazing! This exactly solves the question. Great extension for other purposes too. 

Comment: If you want to have the focus on the newly opened tab (on the left), you have to use: `^+lbutton::
    send ^{lbutton}
    send ^{tab}
    send !+{left}
return`

Comment: After trying it a while, I saw that we need to wait some milliseconds before executing the tab switch. This is my recent script that works so far: `^+lbutton::
    send ^{lbutton}
 Sleep, 150
    send !+{right}
 Sleep, 150
    send ^+{tab}
return`

Comment: super awesome. Anything similiar for mac ?

Answer (score 5):

There is an extension for that. It is called [TabPlus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabsplus/nikomkkhhpfoeamojhhgpfkpkdlfhfii)
It lets you specify where you want your new tabs to open. The behavior will be persistent though. I don't think you can quickly switch between two methods using a hotkey.

[image]

There is also [Tab Position Customizer 2](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-position-customizer-2/jglbflnkbgbklegdblkohbbbheeeklej?hl=en) extension which does the same:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the extensions. However, the left-tab-opening should only happen with a certain shortcut, not persistently.